# Testing a Rest Api which accepts a zip file as input

Tags: java, rest, testing, jersey

I have a rest Api like below.

```
@POST
@Path("/importFile")
@Consumes("application/zip")
@ApiOperation(value = "Importing File")
public List<String> importFile(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
    return importFile(zipInputStream);
}
```

How can I test it ?

Comment: [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29359524/2587435)

Comment: Or use something like postman, if you are looking for manual tests

Answer (score 1):

You can use a curl tool -

```
curl -v -F file=@file1.txt -F http://testYouFile/endpoint
```

You can also use chrome add-ons like postman or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo