# Mock Retrofit service with Mockito causes ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito, retrofit

I tried with:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.26-beta'
```

...

```
public interface CustomerService {
    @POST("url")
    Observable<Session> createSession(@Body Credential credential);
}
```

...

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginActivityTests {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        customerService = Mockito.mock(CustomerService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginGoToNextScreen() throws Exception {
       doReturn(new Session"token")).when(customerService).createSession(
           new Credential("aa", "123", new Device("asd", ":)")));
    }
```

But it crash always.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:30)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:35)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:12)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:11)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:23)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:44)
at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:1101)
at com.pickupnow.customer.LoginActivityTests.setUp(LoginActivityTests.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:257)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:228)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
... 41 more
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I always test like:

```
when(customerService.createSession(any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(new Session("token")));
```

If you need to specify what parameter must be used, instead of `any()`, you could write your `ArgumentMatcher` (http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html). I hope this helps.

Comment: I support proguard and I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/Mockito` why? I use `-keep class org.mockito.** { *; }
-keep interface org.mockito.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.mockito.** { *; }`

Comment: I have no idea about proguard... does it work when proguard is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [MockRestAdapter](http://androidTestCompile%20'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.9.0').

It is simple, just need to create a `MockedService` that implements the original Service declaration, create an instance and set it to your code service instance:

Before each tests...:

```
MockOrderService.mock(new Order("fake-data"))
```

Example of a mocked service:

```
public class MockOrderService implements OrderService {

    private Order mOrder;

    public static void mock(Order order){
        mOrder = order;

        // Setup MockRestAdapter without delays or posible errors
        MockRestAdapter mockRestAdapter = MockRestAdapter.from(ApiManager.REST_ADAPTER);
        mockRestAdapter.setDelay(0);
        mockRestAdapter.setErrorPercentage(0);
        mockRestAdapter.setVariancePercentage(0);

        // Create the mocked service and replace it in
        MockOrderService mockOrderService = new MockOrderService();
        mockOrderService.mOrder = order;

        // Replace the service instance with the mocked one
        // Then every time that the projec call Order.get will return what we 
        // had in our MockOrderService.get() code
        Order.SERVICE = mockRestAdapter.create(OrderService.class, mockOrderService);
    }

    // OrderService override
    @Override
    public Observable<Order> get(@Path("id") String id) {
        return Observable.just(mOrder);
    }

}
```

`Order.SERVICE` should be the instance that the project uses for requests.

Take a look to this post [MakinGIANTS Post](http://makingiants.com/blog/mock-retrofit-service-using-mockrestadapter-and-espresso/).

**---EDIT---**
If you are trying to unit test your app is easier to mock if you wrap your retrofit service inside some kind of repository, then you can mock the repository functions itself.

Comment: link to MakinGIANTS Post. broken

Comment: @k1eran should be fixed.

Comment: @WonkotheSane I updated the answer, the comment was about mocking the retrofit service itself instead of mocking the repository itself, its easier.