# jersey test framework documentation doesn't work

Tags: java, rest, jersey-test-framework

Trying to build a hello world jersey test. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.5.1/test-framework.html makes it look so simple, but when overriding the configure method as documented doesn't work.

From the documentation

```
package api;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;

public class JerseyTester extends JerseyTest {

@Path("hello")
public static class HelloResource {
    @GET
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}


@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
}

@Test
public void testHelloWorld() {
    WebResource webResource = resource();
    String responseMsg = webResource.path("helloworld").get(String.class);
    assertEquals("Hello World", responseMsg);
}
```

}

The issue is the configure method override doesn't work - I get the error: "The return type is incompatible with JerseyTest.configure()". I also get the error: "Cannot instantiate the type ResourceConfig" - how can that be when the documentation explicitly says to instantiate it?!

This is so basic I don't know why it wouldn't work. I'm just trying to get a plain-jane jersey endpoint under test.

Here's my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1'

compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.19'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19'

compile 'com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:2.2.0'
compile 'com.yammer.metrics:metrics-servlet:2.2.0'
compile 'com.yammer.metrics:metrics-jersey:2.2.0'
compile 'com.yammer.metrics:metrics-graphite:2.2.0'

compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'

testCompile 'junit:junit-dep:4.10'
testCompile 'com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-grizzly2:1.19'
testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
}
```

Comment: Adding information to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you're looking at the wrong documentation. The documentation you're looking at is for Jersey 2.x. But you are using Jersey 1.x. You could look at the documentation for [1.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#test-framework), but there's not much going on there. Best thing to do is look at the [source code tests](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/test/framework) for examples. You can also see another example at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359524/2587435)

Comment: Doh, classic mistake. Thanks